# How do I get this to return what I want from the web page using rvest in R

Tags: r, rvest

```
theUrl<- paste('insert url here') 
theactualUrl <- theUrl
webpage <- read_html(theactualUrl) 
stuff_data_html <-    html_nodes(webpage, 'h2') 
stuff_data<- html_text(newslines)    
stuff_data
```

It constantly returns character(0) and not the text from the web page that I want

Comment: I think there is a typo in your code. It should be `stuff_data<- html_text(stuff_data_html) `

Comment: I changed that now but it still returns the same thing @Edu

Comment: `library(dplyr) data <- read_html()

var <- data %>% html_nodes("h2) %>% html_text()`